# Property of Wiener process sample path

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process

What is a mean of time, when the trajectory of wiener process $W_t$ is over the line $y=t$?

We need to find $\mathbb{E}\tau$, where $\tau=\sum\limits_{a,b:\forall t\in(a,b)
; W_t>t}\left(b-a\right)$.

By the law of iterated logarithm $P\left(sup\{t: W_t>t\}<\infty\right)=1$. Then we could find a sequence $t_i$ of points where $W_{t_i}=t_i$.

By local modulus of continuity there is infinite set of such points near $0$.

Then $\tau=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(t_n-t_{n-1}\right)$. How to find it's mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of $\tau$ is flawed, actually,
$$\tau=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{W_t\gt t}\,\mathrm dt,$$ hence $$E(\tau)=\int_0^\infty P(W_t\gt t)\,\mathrm dt.$$
For every $t$, $W_t$ is normal centered with variance $t$ hence $$P(W_t\gt t)=P(Z\gt\sqrt{t}),$$ where $Z$ is standard normal. By symmetry, $P(Z\gt\sqrt{t})=P(Z\lt-\sqrt{t})$ hence
$$
2P(Z\gt\sqrt{t})=P(Z\gt\sqrt{t})+P(Z\lt-\sqrt{t})=P(Z^2\gt t),$$ which implies finally
$$E(\tau)=\frac12\int_0^\infty P(Z^2\gt t)\,\mathrm dt=\frac12E(Z^2)=\frac12.$$

Comment: Why $E(\tau)$ is equal to that integral?

Comment: It should be $\mathbb{E}_{\tau}=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}P\left(\tau>t\right)dt$.

Comment: The answer should be $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Argh, yes, I posited that $P(Z\gt\sqrt{t})=P(Z^2\gt t)$ which is absurd since $[Z^2\gt t)=(Z\gt\sqrt{t})\cup(Z\lt-\sqrt{t})$, hence the factor $\frac12$. Thanks for notifying me. (Unfortunately, your two other comments seem quite offtopic, can you explain them?)

Comment: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Continuous_distribution_taking_non-negative_values). Why $\int\limits_0^\infty P\left(\tau>t\right)dt=\int\limits_0^\infty P\left(W_t>t\right)dt$?

Comment: Because of the representation of $\tau$ which is written ONE LINE ABOVE.

Comment: I noticed that representation, but I could not understand why this equality follows from representation.

Comment: Then ask about it, not about the integrated version! You defined $\tau$ as the amount of time when $W_t\gt t$, right? This is the Lebesgue measure of the (random) set $A=\{t\gt0\mid W_t\gt t\}$, that is, $$\tau=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{t\in A}\,\mathrm dt.$$

Comment: I understood that representation, but not this equality $\mathbb{E}_\tau=\int\limits_0^\infty P\left(\tau>t\right)dt=\int\limits_0^\infty P\left(\int\limits_0^\infty 1_{W_s>s}ds>t\right)dt=(here)=\int\limits_0^\infty P\left(W_t>t\right)dt$

Comment: Actually, by the representation of $\tau$ and by Tonelli(-Fubini) theorem, $$E(\tau)=\int_0^\infty E(\mathbf 1_{t\in A})\mathrm dt,$$ and, for every $t$, $E(\mathbf 1_{t\in A})=P(t\in A)=P(W_t\gt t)$. This does not use the (valid but irrelevant) identity $$E(\tau)=\int_0^\infty P(\tau\gt t)\mathrm dt,$$ which seems to obsess you...